# Stripe does not show payment sheet

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I do receive the client secret and all my test payments are shown on stripe dashboard. However when calling present payment it gives me the error 'No payment sheet has been initialized yet'.

````
    // calling func on cloud functions
    // create payment intent
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://us-central1-wpbakery-52166.cloudfunctions.net/stripePayment');

    final response =
        await http.get(url, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    _paymentIntent = json.decode(response.body);

    print(_paymentIntent);

    await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
        paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
      paymentIntentClientSecret: _paymentIntent['paymentIntent'],
      applePay: true,
      style: ThemeMode.dark,
    ));

    await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the flutter_stripe library?

If so, then you need to also be passing in `merchantCountryCode` in SetupPaymentSheetParameters since the docs mention that it's required when Apple Pay is enabled [[1]](https://pub.dev/documentation/stripe_platform_interface/latest/stripe_platform_interface/SetupPaymentSheetParameters/applePay.htmlhttps://pub.dev/documentation/stripe_platform_interface/latest/stripe_platform_interface/SetupPaymentSheetParameters/applePay.html).

You should also make sure you set `Stripe.merchantIdentifier` before calling `initPaymentSheet`.